# yii activerecord return object

Tags: arrays, object, activerecord, yii2

I am using using yii2 to in basic template with MySQL database
Why This code returns an object instead of an array of selected records from Database
when i use var_damp($rooms) the output is seems an object and not an array of selected record in array format;
any body can help

```
 public function actionIndexFiltered()
    {
        $query = Room::find();

        $searchFilter = [
            'floor' => ['operator' => '', 'value' => ''], 
            'room_number' => ['operator' => '', 'value' => ''], 
            'price_per_day' => ['operator' => '', 'value' => ''], 
        ];

        if(isset($_POST['SearchFilter']))
        {
            $fieldsList = ['floor', 'room_number', 'price_per_day'];

            foreach($fieldsList as $field)
            {
                $fieldOperator = $_POST['SearchFilter'][$field]['operator'];
                $fieldValue = $_POST['SearchFilter'][$field]['value'];

                $searchFilter[$field] = ['operator' => $fieldOperator, 'value' => $fieldValue];

                if( $fieldValue != '' )
                {
                    $temp1=$query->andWhere([$fieldOperator, $field, $fieldValue]);
                }
            }
        }
        $room1=$temp1->all();
        $rooms = $query;

        return $this->render('indexFiltered', [ 'rooms' => $rooms, 'searchFilter' => $searchFilter,'room1'=>$room1 ]);



    }
```

Output is like this and this shows that this code return a  query object and not an array of query execution on database ,
so i checked the code using var_dump function the results is that it is returning a object not array

```
 object(yii\db\ActiveQuery)[70]
      public 'sql' => null
      public 'on' => null
      public 'joinWith' => null
      public 'select' => null
      public 'selectOption' => null
      public 'distinct' => null
      public 'from' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'room' (length=4)
      public 'groupBy' => null
      public 'join' => null
      public 'having' => null
      public 'union' => null
      public 'params' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      private '_events' (yii\base\Component) => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      private '_behaviors' (yii\base\Component) => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'where' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '=' (length=1)
          1 => string 'room_number' (length=11)
          2 => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'limit' => null
      public 'offset' => null
      public 'orderBy' => null
      public 'indexBy' => null
      public 'emulateExecution' => boolean false
      public 'modelClass' => string 'app\models\Room' (length=15)
      public 'with' => null
      public 'asArray' => null
      public 'multiple' => null
      public 'primaryModel' => null
      public 'link' => null
      public 'via' => null
      public 'inverseOf' => null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code return an a dataProvider  .. alias the code for get models /active record

```
$query = Room::find();
```

for obtain the all the  models you can use

```
$roomModels= Room::find()->all();
```

in this the result is a collection of obejct (models)  of class  Room

if you need  an array you can use

```
$roomArray = Room::find()->asArray()->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `$temp1` is the same as `$query`. `andWhere()` method returns `$this` which means that

```
$temp1 = $query->andWhere([$fieldOperator, $field, $fieldValue]);
```

makes `$temp1` to be the same as `$query` which is object of `yii\db\ActiveQuery`.

Now you are calling this:

```
$room1 = $temp1->all(); // the same as $room1 = $query->all();
```

and **this** holds array of `Room` objects while

```
$rooms = $query;
```

is just another unnecessary assignment because `$rooms` is the same as `$query` which is object of `yii\db\ActiveQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the reason for this problem is that 
I must call asArray() member function of ActiveRecord class to generate an array output
`$room1=$temp1->all();` will changed to `$room1=$temp1->asArray()->all();`